# Singular values of compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $T$ be a compact operator.Then show that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$M_n(T)=\sup\{||PT||_1:P\mbox{  is a rank } N\mbox{  projection}\}$  where $M_n$'s are the singular values of $T$ and $||A||_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  M_n(A)$.

I am trying to prove this result by using the fact that $M_i(PT)$||$<$||$P$||$M_i(T)$ but am unable to get the final result.Thanks for any help.